# Assigning and retrieving bit-wise memory value for Genetic Algo

Tags: c++, memory-management, genetic-algorithm, memset

I came across this code for developing a class for GA/GP but failed to understand it and hence unable debug the program.

```
typedef struct {
    void *dataPointer;
    int length;
} binary_data;

typedef struct {
    organism *organisms; //This must be malloc'ed
    int organismsCount;
    int (*fitnessTest)(organism org);
    int orgDnaLength;
    unsigned int desiredFitness;
    void (*progress)(unsigned int fitness);
} evolutionary_algorithm;
```

The above is straight forward. Then we try to initiate organism before testing their fitnness etc...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    evolutionary_algorithm ea;
    ea.progress = progressDisplayer;
    ea.organismsCount = 50;
    ea.orgDnaLength = sizeof(unsigned int);

    organism *orgs =(organism *) malloc(sizeof(organism) * ea.organismsCount);
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        organism newOrg;
        binary_data newOrgDna;
        newOrgDna.dataPointer = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
        memset(newOrgDna.dataPointer, i, 1);
        newOrgDna.length = sizeof(unsigned int);
        newOrg.dna = newOrgDna;
        orgs[i] = newOrg;
    }
```

As far as i understand is the memset() tries to write a binary value into that memory location void pointer (newOrgDna.dataPointer) and so on. But i cant figure how to reassemble all those binary values to get the integer value assigned to variable "dna" of newOrg so that i check the integer value assign to the an individual organism and eventually the entire population residing in the entire memory location which has been assigned to "orgs".

As you guess from above, i not very familiar memory management at this deep level of details so your help is very much appreciated.

Thank you so much

Comment: 9 questions, 0 accepted. Please accept a few answers if you want people to keep on answering your questions.

Comment: Sure I will try to answer some questions as my programming skills are rather limited but will do my best. Is there a way to find filter intermediate level questions perhaps.

Comment: Cicada asked you to confirm (via the acceptance method of this web site) that the answers to your question are good.

Comment: Where is that code from? Most of the major GA frameworks (I confirm for ECJ and OpenBEAGLE) provide ways (if the language doesn't) to convert the binary value of an individual to int/float.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks a bit strange. This line:

```
newOrgDna.dataPointer = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
```

will allocate probably 4 bytes (or 8 on 64 bit machines). Strange part is that `memset` in line just below will set only first byte.

To get actual value you might do:

```
char val = *((char*) newOrgDna.dataPointer);
```

But, as I said, this code looks a bit off. I would rewrite it as:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    organism newOrg;
    binary_data newOrgDna;
    unsigned int * data =  (unsigned int*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    *data = i;
    newOrgDna.length = sizeof(*data);
    newOrgDna.data = (void*) data; // I think that cast can be dropped
    newOrg.dna = newOrgDna;
    orgs[i] = newOrg;
}
```

Then everywhere you want to get data from `organism *` you can do:

```
void f( organism * o )
{
    assert( sizeof(unsigned int) == o->dna.length );
    unsigned int data = *((unsigned int*) o->dna.data);
}
```

Also this is rather a C question not C++.

Comment: I have experimented with your suggestion and modified it to newOrgDna.dataPointer =malloc(sizeof(int));memset((void*)newOrgDna.dataPointer, i, sizeof(int)); which seems to be giving the same results but cant retrieve the unterlying integer held by dataPointer by using: int c=*(int*)((newOrgDna.dataPointer)); what am i doing wrong here? Again thank you for all your help.

Comment: Read specification of `memset` (note that `int` is at leas few bytes, and memset sets **each** of those bytes to value `i`). Stop using it here, as you do not need it.